# Can URLs be redirected on a hosted Wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, permalinks

If I have a blog on another blogging service which has category-based URLs like

```
http://something.com/news
http://something.com/downloads
```

can I transfer it to a hosted Wordpress blog and still have those URLs work or redirect?

Wordpress.com only seems to allow

```
http://something.com/category/news
http://something.com/category/downloads
```

is there any way to make this work? Will Wordpress implement it for me as a paid service? Is there any other way to make redirects or url rewrites work?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using WordPress's [Rewrite Rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) feature. It allows you define pretty urls that can be mapped to URLs that WordPress understands.

WordPress.com won't support this out of the box. For that you'll need to be a VIP customer, and add a custom plugin that adds such rewrite rules.

With a self-hosted WordPress.org site you will be able to do this by adding a few rewrite rules to your `functions.php` or in a custom plugin.

For instance, below I mapped `/news` to a `news` category.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  '^news', 'index.php?category_name=news', 'top'
);
```